# How to rename current database in pgadmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to rename a DB in pgAdmin 4. But I this get error: ERROR: current database cannot be renamed.

What's the process for renaming a database in pgAdmin (the docs are USELESS)? And google can't provide a solution.

Comment: Connect to a different database, then run `alter database .. rename to ...` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

Answer (score 8):

Using pgAdmin 4,

1) switch to the dashboard view

2) select the database to be renamed, right-click it and select Disconnect Database

3) Again select the database to be renamed, right-click it and select properties

4) change the name of the database in the Database field -click save

[image]

Comment: This does not work, as the database will reconnect with every right-click. even when opening this dialogue and disconnecting the DB afterwards, renaming will lead to a prompt showing connection lost.

Answer (score 2):

right click on db name and Properties, then change the name and click Save[image]:

Or just click on other db (eg postgres), open query tool and run

```
alter database "old" rename to "new";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to rename the database you are connected to.
Switch to a different db and then execute the ALTER command.